# Pandas aggregating hours in group by

Tags: pandas, datetime, group-by, aggregate-functions, hour

I have this table:

| Date | User ID | Calls | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3-9-2022 | 2234 | 10 | 01:06:19 |
| 3-9-2022 | 2234 | 4 | 00:32:54 |

That  I want to group into (resetting index as well):

| Date | User ID | Calls | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3-9-2022 | 2234 | 14 | 01:39:13 |

I am getting stuck into aggregating the hours, I read that you have to convert it first into timedelta but I am not sure how to put the function into group by (perhaps with lambda?). In addition I have Calls applied with normal sum function. Here is my current code:

```
df.groupby(['Date','UserID'])['Calls','Hours'].apply(lambda x : x.astype(int).sum()).reset_index()
```

Data type: 
Date - Datetime 
UserID - Int 
Calls - Int 
Hours - Datetime (Time)

Any help appreciated!

**ANSWER**

```
df['Hours'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Hours'])

df_group = df.groupby(['Date', 'User ID']).agg({'Calls':'sum', 'Hours':'sum'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column `Hours` to timedeltas, aggregate `sum` and then convert back to `HH:MM:SS` format:

```
def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 


out = (df.assign(Hours = pd.to_timedelta(df['Hours']))
          .groupby(['Date','User ID'], as_index=False)[['Calls','Hours']]
          .sum()
          .assign(Hours = lambda x: x['Hours'].apply(f)))
print (out)
       Date  User ID  Calls     Hours
0  3-9-2022     2234     14  01:39:13
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get KeyError Hours, it seems by the last assign

Comment: @rayyar - So working well first part `df.assign(Hours = pd.to_timedelta(df['Hours']))` ?

Comment: @rayyar - Or there are some spaces in column names, is possible check it by `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: I see that you can do normal sum operation with timedelta data type. So after convert it to timedelta I group it with aggregate function and it works now. Thank you!